# Pragmatically is there any popular interpretive language that first generates the Syntax tree when parsing?

Tags: compiler-theory

It seems all scripting languages like PHP ,Perl doesn't build any syntax tree,but interpret it directly(no separate syntax parsing & code generation):

https://svn.php.net/repository/php/php-src/trunk/Zend/zend_language_parser.y

is there any popular interpretive language that first generates the Syntax tree when parsing at all?

Comment: LISP: bringing you AST execution since 1958 :-} LISP pretty much builds a syntax tree directly, because its syntax  (nested s-expressions) *is* a tree (and designed to be that way).  So after a "trivial" parse and tree-build, the LISP read-eval-print loop executes the tree directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you have regarding Perl is incorrect:

> At compile time, the interpreter parses Perl code into a syntax tree. At run time, it executes the program by walking the tree.

(Source: [perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) wikipedia page.)

You'll find information about modules you can use to visualize that syntax tree in the  [Core modules](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-modules-B.html) documentation.

Comment: But why it seems it's parsing it directly? http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/HEAD:/perly.y

Comment: Yes, that's the usual way of building a syntax tree.

Comment: But I don't see any logic that resembles building a syntax tree... can you give a detailed example??

Comment: From the link you posted: "The main job of of this grammar is to call the various newFOO() functions in op.c to build a syntax tree of OP structs." That very file you link to is doing just that.

Comment: Finally a function pointer is pointed to the generated code and called,is it right?

Comment: Probably not. The interpreter probably gets passed a pointer to the syntax tree and operates on that. Function pointers might be involved, but probably not for the "toplevel" interpreter start.

Answer (score 0):

Nearly all of them. Interpreting from a token stream is *hard* (and interpreting without even a tokenizer is *even harder*), as you'd need to do much of the parsing work anyway (only this time ad hoc, without the help of parser generators, mixing parser logic with interpreter logic). For starters, getting operator precedence right seem to require potentially infinite lookahead/backtracing if you try it without building intermediate data structures (AST).

One exception might be shell scripting languages due to their dead-simple syntax (mostly just invocations of external programs, variable assignments that operate on strings anyway, and simple loop structures), although I wouldn't bet on it. Edit: Nope, bash has a [yacc grammar](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/parse.y), and zsh seems to have a fully-blown [parser](http://zsh.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=zsh/zsh;a=blob;f=Src/parse.c;h=5b6f099490a8e7c0952de5e3199d908484e0367e;hb=HEAD) as well.

Many of those languages don't stop at the AST either but go on to compile it to bytecode (even if they don't save it for later runs by default - e.g. PHP) and interpret *that*.

Comment: Did you look over the link ? Can you tell me how PHP is building the tree? It seems to me that it's parsing directly..

Comment: @Je Rog: It's using [`yacc`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc) in exactly the file you linked to. Below the line that says `%% /* Rules */`, the grammar is defined. Yacc compiles that to a LALR parser which then reads tokens (generated by a tokenizer described in the same file, above the grammar, look for `%token ...` lines) and applies the "actions" in the .y file to produce a parse tree. It may be cleaned up later in another file. The parsing algorithm used (LALR) is pretty ugly to read/write for humans, but the general idea is described at wiki.

Comment: I know well that it's using lexer/yacc,but I just don't find any evidence to prove that it's FIRST building a tree THEN parse. It seems it's doing it at the same time **according to the code** I linked.

Comment: @Je Rog: Of course it builds the tree while parsing the code. That's exactly what's to be expected, and pretty much the definition of parsing. If it didn't, it had merely checked if the input is valid and had to do the same work again - this time generating a tree along the way - to get a usable result. It just doesn't interpret the code while parsing and building the AST, which is what you originally asked for, isn't it?

Comment: In the link I give,is `zend_do_end_compilation` the function that kick off the code generation step?

Comment: @Je Rog: Honestly, I don't know enough about the internals of PHP about to tell for sure what it does even after looking at the source - it doesn't *look* like it's generating any code though. It's what happens after the file is parsed, that's for sure, but perhaps (that's what I would do, at least) the code generation is instead started by the same code that called the parser.